# Mac terminal : terminate tail output

Tags: mac, terminal, tail

How can I terminate the tail log output on the mac terminal and come back to the prompt?

I have tried using command+z|x|c|q and control+z|x|c|q but it doesn't work.

With control, I get the below output

^X^C^Z^X^C

and the command doesn't do anything

I have to open a new terminal window every time, which exhausts all CLI sessions.

Comment: Control-C should do it. If it doesn't, that suggests the terminal driver is in some weird mode. Try running `stty -a`, and look in the "cchars" section for "intr = ^C"; it should be there if everything is normal. Also, try running `stty sane` before using `tail`, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: In the "cchars" it is intr=^C and also tried `stty sane` but no luck.